# Otto event bus runtime subscription for events

Tags: android, observer-pattern, otto

Is it possible in `Otto` to subscribe to events without using `@Subscribe` annotation ?

In my use case I do not know to which event my object should subscribe to at compile time. I wish to do it at runtime based on certain rules.

Comment: Maybe do it with different Object types

Comment: It's not possible. https://github.com/square/otto/blob/a85ae721d337d9129eb49f5dc90c8e65d49d48ca/otto/src/main/java/com/squareup/otto/AnnotatedHandlerFinder.java#L72

Comment: @SimonMarquis can you please explain ?

Comment: One Object A would subscribe to some Event, and some other Object B would subscribe to other Events. Then at runtime, instantiate the object with the subscribed events you want.

Comment: thats doesn't seem like a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can use a workaround like this,

```
public class MainClass {    

    private EventObserver eventObserver;

    public MainClass() {
        if(...someCondition...) {
            eventObserver = new FirstEventObserver();
        } else {
            eventObserver = new SecondEventObserver();
        }
    }

    public onEvent(Event event) {
        if (event instanceOf FirstEvent) {
            ... handle event ...
        } else if (event instanceOf SecondEvent) {
            ... handle event ...
        }
    }
}

public abstract class EventObserver {

    protected MainClass mainClass;

    public void setMainClass(MainClass mainClass) {
        this.mainClass = mainClass;
    }

    protected void notifyMainClass(Event event) {
        if (mainClass != null) {
            mainClass.onEvent(event);
        }
    }
}

public class FirstEventObserver extends EventObserver {

    public FirstEventObserver() {
        bus.subscribe(this);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(FirstEvent event) {
        notifyMainClass();
    }
}


public class SecondEventObserver extends EventObserver {

    public SecondEventObserver() {
        bus.subscribe(this);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(SecondEvent event) {
        notifyMainClass();
    }
}

public abstract class Event {
}

public abstract class FirstEvent extends Event {
}

public abstract class SecondEvent extends Event {
}
```

Another workaround, which is a much cleaner solution. You can generate the event at runtime with the type you want.

```
public class MainClass {
    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        if (event.getType() == EventType.FIRST_EVENT) {
            ... handle event ...
        } else if (event.getType() == EventType.SECOND_EVENT) {
            ... handle event ...
        }
    }
}

public class Event {
    public enum EventType {
        FIRST_EVENT,
        SECOND_EVENT
    }

    private EventType eventType;

    public Event(EventType eventType) {
        this.eventType = eventType;
    }

    public EventType getType() {
        return eventType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a framework for subscribing to events in runtime with Otto. Instead of having different Model classes for different event types one can have different `EventDelegate` for different events. These event delegate will just receive and event and pass them on to subscriber classes.
A Typical `EventDelegate` will look like this

```
public abstract class OttoEventDelegate {
private OttoEventListener ottoEventListener;

public OttoEventDelegate(OttoEventListener ottoEventListener) {
    this.ottoEventListener = ottoEventListener;
}

public void register() {
    BaseApplication.getInstance().getBus().register(this);
}

public void unregister() {
    BaseApplication.getInstance().getBus().unregister(this);
}

public OttoEventListener getOttoEventListener() {
    return ottoEventListener;
}

public void setOttoEventListener(OttoEventListener ottoEventListener) {
    this.ottoEventListener = ottoEventListener;
}
}
```

This Approach is explained [in this article](http://moldedbits.github.io/tech,/android/2016/07/08/runtime-subscriptions-in-Otto.html). Also if you want to have a look at implementation. Its on github [here](https://github.com/abhishekBansal/OttoRuntime).